# Which characters have playable routes?

Tags: katawa-shoujo

Which of the characters that you interact with in *Katawa Shoujo* have playable routes?

Answer (score 4):

Emi Ibarazaki, Lilly Satou, Shizune Hakamichi, Rin Tezuka, and Hanako Ikezawa each have separate routes, though there is still a lot of interaction with the other characters in most of the possible storylines. Lilly and Hanako's routes in particular have a lot in common.

Comment: There is also the "route" you get when not choosing any of the 5 above. The related Scene is titled "Manly Picnic". You can try it if you want, but it is not that nice of a "route" ;)